# Updating a struct value in mapping

Tags: solidity, mapping, struct

I am trying to update a value in a struct that is mapped. I tried updating a value in the smart contract, it asked me to confirm the transaction but when I check the value it doesn't seem to change please help as I'm new to solidity
My smart contract

```
contract Project {
    string public name;
    uint public postCount = 0;
    uint public docCount = 0;

    mapping(uint => Doc) public Docs;

    struct Doc {
        uint id;
        string title;
        string content;
        address author;
    }

    event DocCreated(
        uint doc_id,
        string title,
        string content,
        address author
    );

    event DocUploaded(
        uint doc_id,
        string title,
        string content,
        address author
    );

    constructor() public  {
        name="project";
    }

    function uploadDoc(string memory _IPFShash, string memory _title) public {
        //upload documents to IPFS get hash then save hash on to blockchain
        docCount++;
        //make a doc
        Docs[docCount] = Doc(docCount, _title, _IPFShash, msg.sender);

        //Trigger Event, solidty provides a way for users to track events and test
        emit DocCreated(docCount, _title, _IPFShash, msg.sender);
    }



    function updateDoc(uint _id, string memory _IPFShash, string memory _title) public {

        for (uint i = 0; i <= docCount; i++) {
            if(Docs[i].id == _id){
                Docs[i].content  = _IPFShash;
            }

        //Trigger Event, solidty provides a way for users to track events 
        emit DocUploaded(_id,  _title, _IPFShash, msg.sender);
        }

    }

}
************************************************************************************
//im calling this with this react script
    updateDoc(id, content, title) {
        this.setState({ loading: true })
        this.state.project.methods.updateDoc(id, content, title).send({ from: this.state.account })
            .on('receipt', (receipt) => {
                console.log('loaded')
            })
        window.location.reload()
    }
```

Comment: Is `loaded` printed?

Comment: `it asked me to confirm the transaction` - who is "it"?

Comment: @goodvibration I think he is referring to metamask.

Comment: @user9080953 add to your ```.on('receipt', your function)``` ```.on('error', (error)=>{console.log(error);})```

Comment: hello Ive added the on error and no errors come back, metamask is asking me to confirm the transaction and it is able to do the transaction but nothing has changed in the struct

Comment: @vteja711: There's a ton of incorrect logics within the contract code itself, making it rather difficult to answer the question cleanly. For example, `Docs` is declared as a mapping but used more like an array. Function `updateDoc`, iterates it between 0 and `docCount`, but including `docCount` instead of excluding it. Function `uploadDoc` starts from `docCount = 1` instead of `0`. Then function `updateDoc` updates also the entry at `0`. The condition `if(Docs[i].id == _id)` may be true even if entry `i` has never been set (when `_id == 0`). And so forth...

Comment: would you suggest that i just an array instead of a mapping (sorry im very new to solidity)

Comment: @goodvibration how would you suggest I change the code, any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: @user9080953 Use mapping only but while updating why are you iterating at all is our question. and also please remove that reload() method, it is taking out the chance to know what the error is....

Comment: Do this directly ```Docs[_id].content  = _IPFShash```. Avoid loops in solidity

Comment: I have tried this method but it does the same thing  it asks me for a confirmation from meta mask and it seems that it has done the update but the value hasnt been changed and no errors(or recepits) are being consoled @vteja711

Comment: `would you suggest that i just an array instead of a mapping` - depending on what it is that you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the contracts in Remix and they kind of work, `updateDoc` might trigger the event `DocUploaded` multiple times and the `_title` is not updated.

The function `updateDoc` doesn't need to iterate over the mapping. It can access the `Doc` directly with `_id`.

```
function updateDoc(uint _id, string memory _IPFShash, string memory _title) public {
    if (Docs[_id].id == _id) {
        Docs[_id].content  = _IPFShash;

        //Trigger Event, solidty provides a way for users to track events 
        emit DocUploaded(_id,  _title, _IPFShash, msg.sender);
    }
}
```

The problem might be that your transaction isn't mined immediately so the changes will not reflect on your dapp when it is reloaded. A common solution is to show a progress bar until the transactions is confirmed.

Answer (score 0):

`mapping(uint => Doc)` maps `[0,1,2,3,4...]` to `{ uint id; string title; string content; address author }`.

instead of trying to set the whole struct at once, set each individual variable of the struct.

```
//old way, doesn't work
//Docs[docCount] = Doc(docCount, _title, _IPFShash, msg.sender);

//new way
Docs[docCount].id = docCount;
Docs[docCount].title = _title;
Docs[docCount].content = _IPFShash;
Docs[docCount].author = msg.sender;

// or try this
(Docs[docCount].id, Docs[docCount].title, Docs[docCount].content, Docs[docCount].author) = (docCount, _title, _IPFShash, msg.sender);
```